# Dynamic TableView Cell to Multiple Detail Views Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

I'm using presentViewController to navigate between two views in XCode. I was wondering how I might select a cell row from a *dynamic tableView* to navigate to a view controller. So, basically, when I tap a dynamic cell, each cell navigates to its own different view. How might I do this?
So far I have this code:

```
@IBAction func press(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

But, instead of using a button, I would like each cell to lead to another particular view as I said above.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array that holds the view controller identifiers:

```
let identifiers = ["newViewController", "newViewController2", "newViewController3"]
```

Implement this UITableViewDelegate method in your view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let identifier = identifiers[indexPath.row] {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your tableView's delegate to the view controller that contains the tableview and that implements the above delegate method.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for the swift (pun intended) response! :D